# ANTLR4 Rule and Token attributes in embedded actions

Tags: antlr4

In the book The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference there are two phrases concerning the access of rule and tokens attributes from embedded actions

Phrase 1 (page 272 Token Attributes) : $T and $l evaluate to Token objects for token name T and token label l. $ll evaluates to List for list label ll.

Phrase 2 (page 273 Parser Rule Attributes) : $r and $rl evaluate to ParserRuleContext objects of type RContext for rule name r and rule label rl . $rll evaluates to List for rule list label rll

I don't understand what the parts

"$ll evaluates to List for list label ll"

and

"$rll evaluates to List for rule list label rll"

mean.

Can you please explain by giving me an example and tell me  how can i use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not completely sure but in some cases the closure operators ( +,* ) are applied to symbols in the RHS of a rule. The net result is the successive invocation of the rules for the symbols (terminal or non-terminals) where the closure is applied. To gather ParserRuleContext or Token objects generated by the closure the “+=“ operator is applied to assign the instantiated objects to a labelled list from which the objects can be later accessed into the rule’s embedded action using the $label notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a bit misleading in the book. What is meant there are token lists. I assume there was an example containing `ll` which didn't make it in the printed book later.

You can have something like:

```
list: ll += ID (ll += ID)*;
```

Note the `+=` which ANTLR translates to a list of tokens (instead of a single token for the simple assignment). You can then access that like an any other list in your language (e.g. `$ll[1].text` for the text of the second element).

Note that there is another case where ANTLR produces a list automatically, namely when you reference a token/rule multiple times in an alt:

```
list: ID COMMA ID;
```

When you now want to access ID in your listener you will see that there is actually a List, so that you can access all occurences.